# Electrical issue 1997 Jetta 2.0

Tags: electrical, battery, vw, jetta, battery-cable

I just bought a 1997 Jetta 2.0 and had to replace the heater core.

As you may know, you need to take off the entire dash and unplug everything in order to get to the heater core. So I replaced the heater core, start to plug everything back in and voilà, no power to the car whatsoever.

I had the battery tested and it's 100 percent so I'm stumped here. The only plug I can't find a home for is a red flat single female plug. For some reason, I'm pretty convinced this is the issue. Any advice for a new Jetta owner?

Comment: Can you take a picture of the plug and describe where it's located?

Comment: When you say "no power to the car whatsoever" -- does that mean that parking lights won't come on, interior lighting not on, trunk lights not functional when trunk open, etc? I'm talking about systems that ALWAYS have power -- not just when the key is turned to accessories.

Comment: If that's the case, I'd start to suspect a much wider problem, not just something that was disconnected in the cabin to pull the dash. I'd head towards the fuse box. Tap a few of those.. are they getting power? Think "big picture" -- follow the flow of the power from the battery to the various systems. If no system in the car is getting power, it's very likely something much closer to the source.